# Multi Day Values

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am having some troubles with my query. I am trying to get the total import rate for the current day, while also matching up the previous day with the correlating hour. 
Example: 1AM (Current Day) = 20 
1AM(Yesterday) = 25.

As of right now the columns Current and Yesterday are showing identical values.

```
SELECT
z.[import Hour],
COUNT(z.orderno) as CurrentDate,
COUNT(od.orderno) as Yesterday 

FROM (

(select datepart(hh, recvtime) as [import Hour], 
orderno 

from mck_hvs.orderheader with (nolock) 

where convert(date, recvtime) = convert(date, getdate()) 
and orderno not like '%ST' 

UNION

select datepart(hh, recvtime) as [import Hour], 
orderno from mck_hvs.oldorderheader with (nolock) 
where convert(date, recvtime) = convert(date, getdate()) 
and orderno not like '%ST' ) as z

Join

 (
select datepart(hh, od.recvtime) as [import Hour], 
od.orderno from mck_hvs.oldorderheader od with (nolock) 
where convert(date, od.recvtime) = convert(date, getdate()-1) 
and od.orderno not like '%ST' ) as OD 
ON z.[import Hour] = od.[import Hour] )

group by z.[import Hour]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use following data:

```
DECLARE @Orders AS TABLE(OrderNo INT,OrderTaken datetime)

INSERT INTO @Orders VALUES(123,'2017-07-24 12:20:24')
INSERT INTO @Orders VALUES(124,'2017-07-24 12:30:24')
INSERT INTO @Orders VALUES(125,'2017-07-24 13:40:24')
INSERT INTO @Orders VALUES(126,'2017-07-24 13:50:24')

INSERT INTO @Orders VALUES(227,'2017-07-25 12:20:24')
INSERT INTO @Orders VALUES(228,'2017-07-25 12:30:24')
INSERT INTO @Orders VALUES(229,'2017-07-25 13:40:24')
INSERT INTO @Orders VALUES(220,'2017-07-25 13:50:24')
```

with output:

[image]

The following SQL:

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME='2017-07-25'
;WITH today AS(
SELECT Cast(OrderTaken As Date) oDate,
CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh,OrderTaken) > 12 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(hh,OrderTaken)-12) + ' PM' WHEN DATEPART(hh,OrderTaken) = 12 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(hh,OrderTaken)) + ' PM' WHEN DATEPART(hh,OrderTaken) < 12 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(hh,OrderTaken)) + ' AM' END As oHour,
Count(OrderNo) OrderCountToday FROM @Orders 
WHERE CAST(OrderTaken AS DATE)=CAST(@Date AS DATE)
GROUP BY Cast(OrderTaken As Date),DATEPart(Hour,OrderTaken)
)
,yesterday AS(
SELECT Cast(OrderTaken As Date) oDate,
CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh,OrderTaken) > 12 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(hh,OrderTaken)-12) + ' PM' WHEN DATEPART(hh,OrderTaken) = 12 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(hh,OrderTaken)) + ' PM' WHEN DATEPART(hh,OrderTaken) < 12 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(hh,OrderTaken)) + ' AM' END As oHour,

Count(OrderNo) OrderCountYesterday 
FROM @Orders 
WHERE CAST(OrderTaken AS DATE)=CAST(@Date-1 AS DATE)
GROUP BY Cast(OrderTaken As Date),DATEPart(Hour,OrderTaken)
)
SELECT t.oDate Today,t.oHour Hour,t.OrderCountToday,y.OrderCountYesterday FROM today t join yesterday y ON  t.oHour=y.oHour and t.oDate=dateadd(day,1,y.oDate)
```

will result as:

[image]

p.s.: You can summarize this SQL a lot if you don't want to use AM/PM thing in the hour. Even the logic for AM/PM can be summarized further but that will show `12 PM` as `0 PM`.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I've included a bit of code up front just to generate some test data. You probably won't need it, but others might.

```
USE sandbox
GO
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Recreate the OP's environment in my sandpit
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mck_hvs.orderheader   --2016 syntax
create table mck_hvs.orderheader(
        recvtime datetime NOT NULL
        ,orderno varchar(20) NOT NULL
)
;
ALTER TABLE mck_hvs.orderheader
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_mck_hvs_orderheader_orderno PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (orderno)
;
GO
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mck_hvs.oldorderheader
;
create table mck_hvs.oldorderheader(
        recvtime datetime NOT NULL
        ,orderno varchar(20) NOT NULL
)
;
ALTER TABLE mck_hvs.oldorderheader
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_mck_hvs_oldorderheader_orderno PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (orderno)
;
GO
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Generate some test data (about two years worth working back from today)
--First the old data (not today's)
INSERT mck_hvs.oldorderheader
SELECT  top 100000 dateadd(mi,abs(checksum(newid())) %1440,dateadd(dd,-abs(checksum(newid())) %720,getdate()-1))  as recvtime
        ,right('0000000' + cast(row_number() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as varchar(20)),7)
         + char(82 + abs(checksum(newid()))%4) + char(82 + abs(checksum(newid()))%4) as orderno--add two random chars from R,S,T,U to the end
FROM sys.columns col1
cross join sys.columns col2
;
--Now today's (assume 500 orders came in)
INSERT mck_hvs.orderheader
SELECT  top 500 dateadd(mi,abs(checksum(newid())) %1440,dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,getdate()),0)) --add a random number of minutes to midnight last night
        ,right('0000000' + cast(row_number() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) +100000 as varchar(20)),7)
         + char(82 + abs(checksum(newid()))%4) + char(82 + abs(checksum(newid()))%4) --add two random chars from R,S,T,U to the end
FROM sys.columns col1
cross join sys.columns col2
;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WITH yesterday /*all my problems seemed so far away*/as 
(
SELECT  datepart(hour,old.recvtime)     as received_hour
        ,count(*)                       as orders_received
FROM    mck_hvs.oldorderheader  as old
WHERE   old.recvtime < dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,getdate()),0)  --Yesterday
        AND old.recvtime >= dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,getdate())-1,0)
        AND old.orderno not like '%ST'   --Note: This is not a SARGable search.
GROUP BY datepart(hour,recvtime)
)
, today as
(
SELECT datepart(hour,ordr.recvtime)     as received_hour
        ,count(*)                       as orders_received
FROM mck_hvs.orderheader as ordr
WHERE ordr.orderno not like '%ST'   --Google "SARG". Trust me.
GROUP BY datepart(hour,ordr.recvtime)
)
SELECT  isnull(yesterday.received_hour,today.received_hour) as received_hour
        ,isnull(yesterday.orders_received,0)                as orders_received_yesterday
        ,isnull(today.orders_received,0)                    as orders_received_today
FROM yesterday
--FULL JOIN in case there are hours of activity in one table that don't exist in the other table.
FULL JOIN today ON yesterday.received_hour = today.received_hour
;
```